# Visual studio 2010 service pack 1 setup always rolling back

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional version installed on my Windows 7 machine.

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Service pack 1.

Every time the installation starts after some time **rollback** starts and installation fails.

I have tried using http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

- Web Installer - this downloaded around 615mb of data and later gave the above error.
- Full ISO - Downloaded the completed ISO for offline setup, was around 1.5 GB but gave the same error.

I am beating my head on this for the past 2 days now. I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2010 also.

**Error details**

Fatal error during installation

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Put the tail of log file on pastebin and show it to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working,

Below are the things I did before re-installing successfully.

- Removed all Visual Stusio addins like Resharper, Akhn SVN and others
- Disabled my Antivirus
- Reboot
- Run setup as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I too had similar rollback issues with SP1.
Did you try verifiyng the ISO checksum as per:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing.aspx

Initially I had a bad checksum so redownloaded the ISO.

Did you try burning the ISO to a DVD, mounting the ISO as virtual drive, or extracting the ISO contents using somethign like 7zip?
I finally managed to get install working correctly when I extracted the ISO contents to a sub folder; I also scanned my hard drive for errors prior to running the setup

- I also ran Disk cleanup prior - to free up disk space (with reference to disk space comment below)

Comment: I had similar problem installing some SP, and the cause was just not enough space on system partition. Not the most probable cause, but easy to check and worth to rule out. Good luck ;)